# What is the best approach to use with ordinal predictors?

Tags: r, regression, ordinal

i'm starting an analysis that has this characteristics:

- One numeric dependent variable (0~10)
- 60 posible independent ordinal variables (likeart 0~5}

i was trying to assume the independents as continous in a multiple regression, but as far as I was looking, it seems to be wrong.

which is the correct way to do a multiple regression with ordinal predictors in r?
Besides that, have i need to check multicollinearity between ordinal predictors? Performe a nonparametric correlation is a good way to choose the best predictors?

Here in Brazil I do not find much information, so I would be very grateful if you could tell me what steps to take you would follow in this project.

Comment: try searching around a bit on stats.stackexchange.com, that site is better suited to more open-ended questions such as this. the answer is: it depends (on what you're trying to accomplish, the size of your data set, etc etc)

Comment: The main goal of the analysis is to predict the personality score y based in the big five inventory  or x (likeart / 60 questions)

Comment: A basic way is to encode them as ordinal (`factor(..., ordered = TRUE)`) and make sure the contrasts are set plausibly.

Comment: You might want to search on "item response model" over on stats.stackexchange.com